# how to use auto-incremented column of one table in another table-mysql workbench 6.2

Tags: mysql

I tried it with the help of this query  "insert into class(faculty_id) select faculty_id from faculty;" but it is inserting already existing values only. Here one column of the table is under auto-increment so I wanted to take this incremented values to another table's column in mysql workbench 6.2. I even tried setting a foreign key between the two columns but it dint work. Please can anyone help out with this issue??

Comment: That's not how auto increment works. Auto increment increments when something is inserted into the table with the auto increment field. If it worked the way you seem to want it to work, the query would never stop

Comment: Yes its true but when I insert values into one table the auto incremented value of a specific record has to be taken by the other record in another table.

Comment: it still doesn't make sense. why should inserting into the class table create a new record in the faculty table?

Comment: As you told I'm inserting values into the table for the auto-increment to work.

Comment: what is the workflow here? create a faculty, and then add classes to it?

Comment: I'm not trying to create a record in another table but I'm trying to bring the values of class 'table' to another record in 'faculty' table.I hope you understood.

Comment: yes I have created faculty and class tables but I want to move the values of faculty_id record in faculty table to faculty_id record in class table.

Comment: but you said this 'but it is inserting already existing values only' - so it sounds like its doing exactly what you want it to do?

Comment: yes. It is not inserting newly added elements. let us suppose if I added some more content after using that query it is not sending those values.

Comment: AH. you want values to be inserted into class AS THEY are inserted into faculty? For that you need a trigger

Comment: Exactly. You got my point now. I'm not familiar with triggers. How can I use it in mysql workbench 6.2

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want i think. an `after insert` trigger will fire every time something is inserted into faculty, and after the data has been inserted.  You can access the values that have just been inserted with the `NEW.` prefix.

```
DELIMITER //
create trigger classInsert after insert on faculty
for each row
begin
  insert into class(faculty_id) values (NEW.faculty_id);
end//
DELIMITER ;
```

And it will automatically add an entry into the `class` table every time you add a new value to `faculty`.

[Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa6e8/1)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75527/discussion-on-answer-by-pala-how-to-use-auto-incremented-column-of-one-table-in).

Comment: Hello Sir, I would like to bring the last_insert_id() of mysql to jsp and it should be preserved in a specific variable so that I can use that value in other table.

Comment: Here is my code Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sairam", "root", "root");
Statement S=con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=S.executeQuery("select last_insert_id(),student_name,date_of_admission from student");

Comment: that's a new question. not a comment on an answer to an unrelated question